# javax.mail.messagingexception could not connect to SMTP host : hostname port:25 response : 552

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am getting **Javax.mail.messagingexception : could not connect to SMTP host : hostname port : 25 response : 552**

Sometime mail is sent successfully. But sometime I get this exception.

I am not clear that why this is happening. If any thing goes wrong then no mail should be sent. But the exception still happens sometimes.

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   mail.mydomain.com, port: 25, response: 552    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)  at
>   com.winit.magicbricks.businessLayer.CommonFunctions$1.run(CommonFunctions.java:1065)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

provide the complete error log.. 552 is a generic response code it could be that either you are spamming  or the recipients mailbox is full.

> You should try adding DKIM signature to your mails and SPF record entry for your domain

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.mydomain.com, port: 25, response: 552 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
 at com.winit.magicbricks.businessLayer.CommonFunctions$1.run(CommonFunctions.java:1065)

Comment: Can u try doing a telnet through command prompt?? The SMTP error message is not shown for some reason. Also since sometimes you are able to send the mail it is clear that there is no connection issue. Its the connecting server which is doing the rate limit. Possibly you are sending too many mails.

Comment: I am able to connect to telnet. I am sending aprox 20 mail in a day. But this type of error may come in first mail also. I am not able to know when this exception came because if same thing is working for first time second time not working.

Comment: without proper error response its tough to analyze the situation. These error message will start comming once you reach the threshold value. May you can try adding DKIM signature to your mails and SPF record entry for your domain.

Comment: I posted the Exception details. The Exception is : 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.mydomain.com, port: 25, response: 552
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)

Comment: I am looking for something like ail Handler[10000]: Exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: `552 4.3.1 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size`

Comment: No I am not getting error like this. I have fixed mail format and I am sending same mail each time. So there is no chance of Message size exceeds.

Comment: Try adding a DKIM signature to your mails 552 error code can correspond to different error messages.

Comment: I am using third party mail server from java code. So, how I can add the DKIM signature.